# program is closing after one frame of the while loop

Tags: python, opencv

I have this program that is supposed to detect light sources and circle them using the open cv library for python. the program works for the first frame of the camera being captured and then when the while loop tries to capture the second frame terminal gives me this error:

```
   VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
    Unable to stop the stream: Device or resource busy
    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 11111
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "lazer.py", line 27, in <module>
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.error: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:11111: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

this seems like a simple fix but I am new to open cv and have never used it before. I think I have to somehow stop the camera in between frames because the error says that the device or resource is busy. Also I would like to make it clear that this is not a repeat of my previous question I was having a different issue before because before I was not getting any image and now I am getting something. Any help would greatly be appreciated here is my code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils import contours
from skimage import measure
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2


    # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to the image file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
while(1):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    #problem is here ********************************************
    ret, image = camera.read()
    #image.shape
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)
    #threshold the image to reveal light regions in the
    # blurred image
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    # perform a series of erosions and dilations to remove
    # any small blobs of noise from the thresholded image
    thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=4)
    # perform a connected component analysis on the thresholded
    # image, then initialize a mask to store only the "large"
    # components
    labels = measure.label(thresh, neighbors=8, background=0)
    mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")

    # loop over the unique components
    for label in np.unique(labels):
        # if this is the background label, ignore it
        if label == 0:
            continue

        # otherwise, construct the label mask and count the
            # number of pixels 
        labelMask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
        labelMask[labels == label] = 255
        numPixels = cv2.countNonZero(labelMask)

            # if the number of pixels in the component is sufficiently
            # large, then add it to our mask of "large blobs"
        if numPixels > 300:
            mask = cv2.add(mask, labelMask)
    # find the contours in the mask, then sort them from left to
    # right
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = contours.sort_contours(cnts)[0]

        # loop over the contours
    for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
            # draw the bright spot on the image
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ((cX, cY), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        #x and y center are cX and cY
        cv2.circle(image, (int(cX), int(cY)), int(radius),
            (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.putText(image, "#{}".format(i + 1), (x, y - 15),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    #cv2.waitKey(1000)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Entirely a guess here as I don't know open cv, but perhaps `camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` should be initialised outside the loop

Comment: @Peter  You are absolutely right. It tries to set the camera device(0) again, and since the device is already captured/assigned in the first iteration of the loop, it says the device is busy the second time.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out I needed camera.release() at the end of my program

Comment: wait @peter your solution was better

Comment: its a best practice to use camera.release() not a must have. 
In your case, if you use it inside the loop, you are consuming camera once, releasing and then doing it again and again. Instead of consuming it once and reading it again and again. Good that you have incorporated @peter's solution